# Access `.csproj` attributes from C# in .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, csproj

My `.csproj` file contains:

```
...
<PackageId>MyProject</PackageId>
<Version>1.0.0</Version>
...
```

How can I access that from my project's code?

Comment: If code can compile without a project, why should it access .csproj?

Comment: It is content of a build file.  You don't deploy your project file to the user's machine, it only exists on your machine.  Nor do you include it in a Nuget package.  If you want to do this anyway, but surely you shouldn't, then just use XmlDocument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To access version and more general properties of your project use:
[`GetCustomAttribute<T>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.customattributeextensions.getcustomattribute?view=netcore-2.0)

Use [`AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyinformationalversionattribute?view=netcore-2.0) as type T to retrieve the Version property.

For other values for T, see the attributes listed on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection?view=netcore-2.0

Example:
`typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>().InformationalVersion`

Comment: This will work for version but not for the PackageId but I don't know the OP's intent. But for all version-related properties, this is the best/correct way.

Comment: @MartinUllrich You're right, I've edited my answer. :)

Comment: Yeah `PackageId` will never be used for anything except for creating Nupkgs and is never part of the dll / any attribute..